# PHP if function has an error

Tags: php, function, if-statement, error-handling

I have a line in my PHP code that looks like this (it calls a function):

```
$objTest->joinServer($servers[array_rand($servers)]);
```

However, sometimes, the function/line throws back an error that continues in an infinite loop. How can I detect if this line throws back an error, and so something else instead?

Currently, I think that I may need to do something like this, but I have no idea how to implement it correctly:

```
$conn = $objTest->joinServer($servers[array_rand($servers)]);

if($conn has some error) {
    // Do this
} else {
    // No error so excute line
    $objTest->joinServer($servers[array_rand($servers)]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    $conn = $objTest->joinServer($servers[array_rand($servers)]);
catch(Exception e) {
    //do something else here
}
```

If an error occurs calling that function, you can output the error with:
    `e->getMessage()`  or 'do something else' as you said. Read the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: I'm still getting the error. However, the error I'm getting is a `Notice` message, does that matter?

Comment: @user2898075 that's the point, since you are catching the error... what is the message?